# mod_rewrite replace query string key

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In short, I'm trying to change the given URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/category/title/attachment/randomstring_?resolution=320x480
```

With

```
http://mydomain.com/category/title/attachment/randomstring_320x480
```

In essence, removing `?resolution=` from the query string and adding the value to the path.

The category, title, and randomstring values are dynamic, but their placement should always be the same.

I don't know if it matters, but this is being used in WordPress.

I tried the following, but I just get a 404:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^resolution=([0-9]{3,4}x[0-9]{3,4})$
RewriteRule ^$ ${REQUEST_URI}%1/? [R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of trial and error (and reading RewriteLog output), I finally got it working with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^resolution=(.*)$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The key issues with the original solution:

- Using `^$` instead of `.` in the `RewriteRule`
- Using `/?` instead of just `?` in the `RewriteRule`
- Not including `,L` in the `RewriteRule` flags

For anyone who is curious, including `?` in the `RewriteRule` prevents the QUERY_STRING from remaining in the request.